# Java: Remove full stop in string

Tags: java, replace

I want to delete all the full stops ( . ) in a string.

Therefore I tried: `inpt = inpt.replaceAll(".", "");`,
but instead of deleting only the full stops, it deletes the entire content of the string.

Is it possible to delete only the full stops? Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Change `"."` to `"\\."`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a regular expressions as an argument, and `.` in a regex means "any character".

You can use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) instead:

```
inpt = inpt.replace(".", "");
```

It will remove all occurences of `.`.

Answer (score 11):

Don't use `replaceAll()`, use `replace()`:

```
inpt = inpt.replace(".", "");
```

It is a common misconception that `replace()` doesn't replace all occurrences, because there's a `replaceAll()` method, but in fact *both* replace all occurrences. The difference between the two methods is that `replaceAll()` matches on a regex (fyi a dot in regex means "any character", which explains what you were experiencing) whereas `replace()` matches on a literal String.

Answer (score 6):

[`String#replaceAll(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a regex. The dot is a regex meta character that will match anything.

Use

```
inpt = inpt.replace(".", "");
```

it will also replace every dot in your `inpt`, but treats the first parameter as a literal sequence, see [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

If you want to stick to regex, you have to escape the dot:

```
inpt = inpt.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to mask the dot

```
inpt = inpt.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll` use a regex, please use the following:

```
inpt = inpt.replaceAll("\\.", "")
```